# Task manager object for lazy initialization

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, lazy

#### The Problem

I am developing a Visual Studio extension for importing code from a server.

Because of the way Visual Studio works, multiple threads could try to perform the same operation at the same time.

Thus, I wanted a class that would ensure that a) each `Task` would only be performed when needed and b) each `Task` would only be performed once.

The only exception to b) is if the requesters cancel and then later another request is made in which case if the operation was not finished, it should be retried.

Intended functionality:

1. A `TaskManager` object is created.
2. At some point, `TaskManager.Value` is called on the object and the `Task` is set to run.
3. If `TaskManger.Value` is called multiple times (possibly on other threads), the other executions are set waiting on the `Task` that is already in progress.
4. If the `CancellationToken` indicates a cancellation request, only if all the requestors agree should the `Task` be cancelled.
5. If the `TaskManager` object is cancelled before completion and later is requested again, the `Task` should be reinitialized.

#### The Code

```csharp
public class TaskManager<T>
{
    readonly Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> _initializer;

    public TaskManager(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> initializer) => _initializer = initializer;

    Task<T>? _task;
    CancellationTokenSource _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    readonly object _initializationLock = new();
    readonly ConcurrentBag<CancellationToken> _cancellationTokens = new();

    public Task<T> Value (CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (cancellationToken != default)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return Task.FromResult<T>(default);

            _cancellationTokens.Add(cancellationToken);
            cancellationToken.Register(() =>
            {
                if (_task is not { IsCompleted: true } && _cancellationTokens.All(c => c.IsCancellationRequested))
                    _cancellationToken.Cancel();
            });
        }

        if (_task != null && !_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return _task;
        lock (_initializationLock)
        {
            if (_task != null) return _task;

            _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            _task = _initializer(_cancellationToken.Token);
        }
        return _task;
    }
}
```

#### Example Usage

```csharp
public static class CodepediaApi
{
    private static readonly RestClient client = new RestClient("https://localhost:5001"); // Test Server
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, TaskManager<SearchResult[]>> responses = new Dictionary<string, TaskManager<SearchResult[]>>();

    public static Task<SearchResult[]> Search(string query, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        responses.TryGetOrAdd(query,
            () => new TaskManager<SearchResult[]>(async c =>
                (await client.GetAsync<SearchResult[]>(new RestRequest("/api/search").AddQueryParameter("q", query), c)) ?? new SearchResult[0]
            )
        ).Value(cancellationToken);
}
```

where `TryGetOrAdd` is defined as follows:

```csharp
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TValue TryGetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> d, TKey key, Func<TValue> toAdd)
    {
        if (d.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value))
            return value;
        TValue adding = toAdd();
        lock (d)
        {
            if (d.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                return value;
            d.Add(key, adding);
        }
        return adding;
    }
}
```

#### Another Example Usage

Here is one of my classes:

```csharp
public class CodepediaUtil
{
    public readonly Workspace Workspace;
    public readonly SnapshotSpan Range;

    public readonly TaskManager<(Document document, SemanticModel semanticModel, SyntaxNode outerNode, UnresolvedMethodCallInfo unresolvedInvocation)?> CodeAnalysisInfo;
    public readonly TaskManager<SearchResult[]> SearchResults;
    public readonly TaskManager<Dictionary<SearchResult, WikiEntry>> SearchResultsInfo;

    public async Task<UnresolvedMethodCallInfo?> UnresolvedInvocation (CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var unresolvedInvocationInfo = await CodeAnalysisInfo.Value(cancellationToken);
        if (unresolvedInvocationInfo is not (_, _, _, UnresolvedMethodCallInfo unresolvedInvocation)) return null;

        return unresolvedInvocation;
    }

    public CodepediaUtil (Workspace workspace, SnapshotSpan range)
    {
        Workspace = workspace;
        Range = range;

        CodeAnalysisInfo = new TaskManager<(Document document, SemanticModel semanticModel, SyntaxNode outerNode, UnresolvedMethodCallInfo unresolvedInvocation)?>
        (
            async (CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            {
                Document? document = Range.Snapshot.TextBuffer.GetRelatedDocuments().FirstOrDefault();
                if (document == null) return null;

                SemanticModel? semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync(cancellationToken);
                if (semanticModel == null) return null;

                SyntaxNode? outerNode = await CodeAnalyzer.GetOuterNodeAsync(semanticModel, Range.Start, cancellationToken);
                if (outerNode == null) return null;

                UnresolvedMethodCallInfo? unresolvedInvocation = outerNode.FindUnresolvedInvocation(semanticModel);
                if (unresolvedInvocation == null) return null;

                return (document, semanticModel, outerNode, unresolvedInvocation);
            }
        );
        SearchResults = new TaskManager<SearchResult[]>
        (
            async (CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            {
                UnresolvedMethodCallInfo? unresolvedInvocation = await UnresolvedInvocation(cancellationToken);
                if (unresolvedInvocation == null) return new SearchResult[0];

                return await CodepediaApi.Search(unresolvedInvocation.Name, cancellationToken);
            }
        );
        SearchResultsInfo = new TaskManager<Dictionary<SearchResult, WikiEntry>>
        (
            async (CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            {
                // UnresolvedMethodCallInfo? unresolvedInvocation = await UnresolvedInvocation(cancellationToken);
                // if (unresolvedInvocation == null) return new Dictionary<SearchResult, WikiEntry>();
                // string invocationName = unresolvedInvocation.Name;

                return await CodepediaApi.InterpretSearchResults(await SearchResults.Value(cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This coding pattern should allow other classes to request exactly what they need on a per-need basis.

#### What I want reviewed

- Is my code useful? (Is there a better way to do this?)
- Could the performance/elegance of my code improved? (Any comments to make it better would be appreciated.)
- Did I make a mistake? (Is my code thread-safe? Are there any race conditions or ways it could get stuck?)

Comment: Maybe it is too Friday to me, but I don't understand the basic problem which you want to solve. *each Task would only be performed once* << A Task can be completed either with failure or with success only once. You can `await` a Task as many times as you want but that will not trigger a new execution. *each Task would only be performed when needed* << what do mean by that? Do want to have a cold start on the Task?

Comment: @PeterCsala, the way it differs from `Task` is that it is not started until the `Value` function is called on it but if multiple calls are made to the `Value` function, the `Task` is only started once.

Comment: Can't you achieve that with a Lazy<Task>?

Comment: @PeterCsala, yeah, it's the same idea but I don't think that it will reinitialize the `Task` if it is cancelled. Eg. a scenario where a user searches for something, cancels and then searches for the same thing again should retry.

Comment: Well that's a valid point. I will review it next week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my observations:

#### `TryGetOrAdd` of `Extensions`

- Naming a parameter to `d` is not really a good choice
- I guess you have performed the `TryGetValue` twice due to the double-checked lock

  - I would like to warn you with [Jon Skeet's words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394898/double-checked-locking-in-net)

> Double-checking locking now works in Java as well as C# (the Java memory model changed and this is one of the effects). However, you have to get it exactly right. If you mess things up even slightly, you may well end up losing the thread safety.

- Locking on the `d` is not a good idea since it is provided by the caller (so, it can be considered as `public)`

  - [Related SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078535/c-sharp-lock-on-reference-passed-to-method-bad-practice)
  - [Pluralsight Best practices](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/lock-statement-best-practices#module-avoidlockingonanythingpubliclyaccessible)
- Instead of having three `return` statements you can achieve the same with two

```
private static readonly object syncObject = new();
public static TValue TryGetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, Func<TValue> toAdd)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value))
        return value;
            
    lock (syncObject)
    {
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            value = toAdd();
            dict.Add(key, value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

#### `TaskManager`

- Is there any particular reason why did you not use target-typed new expression for `_cancellationToken`?

  - By the way `_cancellationToken` is a really bad name for this member since it is a CancellationToken**Source** not a CancellationToken
- It is not absolutely clear for me why did you pass the `initializer` via the ctor and the `cancellationToken` via the `Value` method

  - Can't you pass the the two either via ctor or via the method?
- In case of C# a method usually starts with verb, so `GetValue` or `RetrieveValue` might be better
- If the `IsCancellationRequested` is true then would it make more sense to call `Task.FromCanceled<T>(cancellationToken)` instead?
- Here yet again you can simplify your `lock` block to have a single `return` statement

```
lock (_initializationLock)
{
    if (_task is null)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new();
        _task = _initializer(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    return _task;
}
```

#### `CodepediaApi`'s `Search`

- Here I've only two tiny suggestions

  - `c` is not the best name for `CancellationToken`
  - Instead of allocating empty array (`new SearchResult[0]` rather prefer `Array.Empty<SearchResult>()`

---

**UPDATE #1**: Reflect to the first comment

> The method of creating a static variable called syncObject would mean that only one Dictionary could be accessed at a time by the TryGetOrAdd function. In my code's case that work fine as the only Dictionary is the search dictionary. The issue with using another object as a sync object is that since dict is not locked, the first call to dict.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value) could be accessing the Dictionary while it's an invalid state. So, the only solution would be to surround the whole function with lock (syncObject) which would decrease performance

The core problem here is ownership. Since the dictionary is not owned by the method or the class of the method anyone can access it (and potentially modify it) since the `lock` scope is the method, not the object. Let me demonstrate with a simple example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    var lockAcquired = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    _ = Task.Run(async () => { await lockAcquired.Task; dict.Add("1", 1);});
    Add(dict, lockAcquired);
}

public static void Add(Dictionary<string, int> dict, TaskCompletionSource<object> signal)
{
    lock(dict)
    {
        signal.SetResult(null);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        dict.Add("1", 1);
    }
}
```

This code will throw an exception inside the `Add` method:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1

So, as you can see neither mine nor your solution is fine.

Comment: The method of creating a static variable called `syncObject` would mean that only one `Dictionary` could be accessed at a time by the `TryGetOrAdd` function. In my code's case that work fine as the only `Dictionary` is the search dictionary. The issue with using another object as a sync object is that since `dict` is not locked, the first call to `dict.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value)` could be accessing the `Dictionary` while it's an invalid state. So, the only solution would be to surround the whole function with `lock (syncObject)` which would decrease performance.

Comment: The reason `cancellationToken` is provided in the `Value` function not the constructor is that each requester of the `TaskManager` has their own `cancellationToken`. Providing the initializer in the constructor allows `TaskManager` objects to be passed around without actually starting the task.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 I've updated my post to reflect your first comment, please check it.

Comment: As I understand it, the only failure mode for my existing code is if someone adds a key value pair to the `Dictionary` without locking it while the first `TryGetValue` function is running as once the `Dictionary` is locked `TryGetValue` is called again. I was thinking about what you said about code ownership and I thought that to help improve my code style I could create another class something like `public class MyDictionary<K, V> : Dictionary<K, V> {}`. Then, I could have the `TryGetOrAdd` function only accept `MyDictionary` to prevent misuse with objects managed by other code.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 Since your Dictionary is passed as a parameter that's why any thread can do anything on it (call Add, Remove, Clear or assign null, etc.) with or without locking. If that thread is using a lock as well then the locks will be separate not re-entrant (nested). So, creating a type alias will not solve your problem.

Comment: the plan is that whenever I add to the `Dictionary` I lock it but I don't need to lock on reads. As for making a `MyDictionary` type, that was just for code style to make it clear that the function should only be used on objects you manage.

Comment: @trinalbadger587 Well it depends. Lets suppose you have 3 threads (2 readers, 1 writer) then it might happen that the two reads receive different results. If you have multiple readers and the above behavior is unacceptable then you might need to consider to use a read-write lock. Anyway I don't want to have a too lengthy conversation. If you have any question I'm happy to answer otherwise have a great week!

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about why your comment about `TryGetValue` returning different results for different threads. In my case, the values in the `Dictionary` will never be edited, just added, so I don't see how it's possible for them to give different values. Anyway, I don't want to have too lengthy a conversation either but I just wanted to say thank you for your help. I really appreciate it and a great week to you!